# Phonon crashes python executable

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, phonon

I'm having an issue with the Phonon VideoPlayer I can't find an answer to.

I've boiled it down to the following, trivial example:

```
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import PyQt4.QtCore
import sys

class TestPlayer(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.player = Phonon.VideoPlayer(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.player)

        start = QtGui.QPushButton('Start')
        start.clicked.connect(self.select_and_play)
        layout.addWidget(start)

        self.mediaSource = None

    def select_and_play(self):
        f = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'File :-)')
        print 'playing: %s' % f
        self.mediaSource = Phonon.MediaSource(f)
        self.player.play(self.mediaSource)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'pyqt: %s' % PyQt4.QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR
    print 'py version: %s' % sys.version

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    tester = TestPlayer()
    tester.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Executing this gives:

```
pyqt: 4.11
py version: 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
playing: C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/Wildlife.wmv
```

The next thing happening is that windows informs me that "python has stopped working" with no further, useable error information.
Note that the media file is some windows sample video, which of course plays just fine in any other videoplayer.
This is on windows 7 professional, SP1 using the latest binary installer for PyQt4 from the riverbank website.

I've tried upgrading PyQt4 and successfully ran the PyQt phonon examples.
I don't really know where to start looking for the issue from this point on...

Comment: Did you try debugging it - i.e. see what line of code is hit when Python stops responding?

Comment: Yes and no. The last line of python code executed is `self.player.play(self.mediaSource)`. Presumably because the videoplayer player works asynchronously, it then takes a little moment until python crashs. So the actual crash probably happens somewhere within the C/C++ part of python or PyQt...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Phonon, so is self.mediaSource a simple string? If so, try renaming your `Sample Videos` directory to `Sample_Videos` (so that it does not contain spacing). Worth a try. I'll try to help you more when I get home.

Comment: No it's not. But the path doesn't matter, I can reproduce the same crash with video files at different paths (without spaces).

Comment: Have  to tried to play your video in one of the phonon examples you have ran.

Comment: I have an update for you: I just tried it on my Linux machine as well as on my Windows machine and loaded one of my WMV files, and it works fine. No crashes, and I can see the video and hear the audio just fine. So it must be something with your local setup or with that particular file.

Comment: That's not new to me. I know this example works on several machines, but it does not work on mine or on the one of a colleague. But, all the machines are running windows7 (64bit), use the same 32bit pythonn and PyQt. No idea what's wrong with my machine :( Or my colleague's fwiw...

Comment: @sebastian, you could use a C debugger (e.g. gdb) to run python. That should show you more exactly where the crash happens if it happens in a C library.

Comment: does it even start playing chosen video or it stops at the moment you click "open"?

Comment: @Aleksandar nope, it does not start at all. It remains all black until it crashes..

Comment: @sebastian how much RAM your machine has? It could be something with GDI memory limits if you are low on RAM. Also, after crash happens you can check if there are any logs in Event Viewer/Windows logs/Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gotcha!

So I tried debugging this with Visual Studio Express, using the pdb files from python.org.
This did not directly help, but Visual Studio revealed that the seg fault appeared in `nvumdshim.dll`, which belongs to my nvidia graphics drivers.

I updated those - and things are working just fine now.